# Increment Div using Javascript for making it work like a Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am making use of div tag to make a custom Progress Bar instead of using HTML5 .  I have write some code which is not working perfectly. Here in the code i am trying to get width of inner div using javascript and parsing it into integer to get width in number format for running the first IF Condition but i am getting the width of inner div null so the first IF Condition will never be executed.
The second IF Condition is simply to check progress is completed then clear the div width back to 0px and close the interval function.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer{
        width:300px; 
        height:50px; 
        background:#000; 
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    #inner{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        margin:2px;
        width:0px; 
        height:46px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var increaseWidth = 0;
    function getID(element){
        return document.getElementById(element);
    }
    function progressBarEvent(){
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
                if(parseInt(getID('inner').style.width) < 296) {
                    getID('inner').style.width = increaseWidth+"px";
                    increaseWidth++;
                }
                if(getID('inner').style.width) == "296px"){
                getID('inner').style.width == "0px";
                increaseWidth = 0;
                clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
            ,5
        );
    }
</script>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="progressBarEvent()">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. You need to give us some more details. In what way is it "not working perfectly"? What happens / what do you want to happen? Are there any errors?

Comment: on button click event i am trying to parse inner div width like var value = parseInt(getID('inner').style.width; and alerting it using alert(value); but i get nothing in alert box...so i want to retrieve inner div width value in integer format

Comment: if you want to make progress bar for upload you can use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that for the very first time when there are no `width` style is set yet, this expression

```
parseInt(getID('inner').style.width)
```

will return `NaN`. So you never actually increase the width. You can fix it like this:

```
if ((parseInt(getID('inner').style.width) || 0) < 296) {
    getID('inner').style.width = increaseWidth + "px";
    increaseWidth++;
}
```

Also validate your code, currently it contains syntax error in this line:

```
if(getID('inner').style.width) == "296px"){
//   extra ) ----------------^
```

And one more problem: change `getID('inner').style.width == "0px";` to `getID('inner').style.width = "0px";` because you mean assignment here, not comparison.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrtkwbx9/1/

Comment: But what to do if i want to make inner div width back to 0 after reaching it 296. what changes to make in 2nd IF Condition

Comment: Good. Feel free to get back if there are other issues with progress bar.